# Rails 4: Redirect Loop with before_filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am setting up a very simple rails app that involves a simple authentication check before you can enter the site. But, when the `before_filter` runs, and the user is redirected to the login path, a redirect loop occurs.

ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_filter :check_session

  private

    def check_session
        redirect_to login_path and return unless current_user?
    end

    def current_user?
        !session[:username].blank?
    end

end
```

SessionsController

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

    def new

    end

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that, since your `SessionsController` inherits from `ApplicationController`, it actually inherits the `before_filter` as well. This means you are not allowing someone to see the login page unless they are logged in, which is usually undesirable behavior. You want to skip this `before_filter` on the login page:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :check_session, only: :new

  def new

  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problem in your routes. One way of solution is defining a root path for your app as:

```
root 'app_entry#index'
```

Then create a controller for it as given below:

```
class AppEntryController < ApplicationController

     def index
      if current_user
        redirect_to 'controller_name/action_name'
      else
        redirect_to '/users/sign_in'
     end

end
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
You should use the before filter like this

before_filter :check_session, :except => [:new]
```